# Adding a WMTS layer with a source projection of EPSG:31259 in OpenLayers results in invalid tiles being requested

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wmts

I'm trying to visualize a publicly accessible WTMS layer in OpenLayers.
The GetCapabilities URL is: https://gis.bgld.gv.at/gisbgld/rest/services/Public/Nur_Flaechenwidmung/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml.

One of the source projection listed is EPSG:31259. So I registered this projection manually using proj4.defs(). However, OpenLayers 6.4.3 still requests incorrect tiles.

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import WMTS, {optionsFromCapabilities} from 'ol/source/WMTS';
import WMTSCapabilities from 'ol/format/WMTSCapabilities';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4';

var parser = new WMTSCapabilities();
var map;

proj4.defs("EPSG:31259","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=750000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs");                           
register(proj4);

fetch('https://gis.bgld.gv.at/gisbgld/rest/services/Public/Nur_Flaechenwidmung/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (text) {
      
      var result = parser.read(text);
      var options = optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
        layer: 'Public_Nur_Flaechenwidmung',
        matrixSet: 'default028mm',
      });
      
      map = new Map({
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),  // <--- Loads correctly
            opacity: 0.7,
          }),
          new TileLayer({
            opacity: 1,
            source: new WMTS(options), // <--- Does not load 
          }) ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
          center: [1759898.89, 5992878.82],
          zoom: 9,
        }),
      });
    });
```

Comment: I'm not claiming that there is anything wrong the with service. Just wanted to know how to load it in OpenLayers. BTW, this is how it looks with their own ArcGIS viewer: https://gis.bgld.gv.at/gisbgld/rest/services/Public/Nur_Flaechenwidmung/MapServer?f=jsapi

Comment: what do you mean by "requests incorrect tiles"? what are the values in the `Options` object you are using?

Comment: I think the WMTS has coordinates in northing easting order.  You need to add `+axis=neu` to the proj4 definition.

Comment: @Mike Excellent! That did the trick, thanks